# How to structure flexible model add/removes within a backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, structure, backbone.js-collections, conceptual

This question is conceptual, hopefully it doesn't cause a fuss.

I'm fairly new to Backbone, especially when it comes to deciding what should be a model and what shouldn't. I'm trying to do something similar to *[Trello's](https://trello.com/) behavior*, where a single card may or may not have a set of UI features like checklist, due date, members and so on. **My question is:**

Can anyone offer ideas on how to structure the "card" to "parts" relationship that would allow me to add/remove individual components from a larger parent. I currently picture a UI piece (i.e. checklist) as it's own model but am unsure how I would connect it to a parent card, which would presumably be a model as well.

I understand models, view, and collections, but due to inexperience have trouble delegating what app component should be what, and how to structure relationships. I'm not looking for "the right" answer as approaches will vary, but more so insight in how people structure their set ups and what common practice may be.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a good answer that's more definitive than 'it depends'. On the UI side, you're probably going to have a parent `card` view and then views that extend the `card` view, like `listCard`, `checkCard` or `textCard`. This allows you to DRY with components of the card view that remain useful across the different types of cards (drag/drop, delete, etc.) but also implement custom behavior for each type of view in the view's subclass (like templates or interface functionality).

On the model side, you will, I presume have a pretty different data structure underlying each card, so for that reason, I'd probably be tempted to create a different model for each card type. But it will ultimately depend on how you want to structure your database, and how different your data behind the card types will be.

Comment: So heres the thing that tripped me up about Trello's concept. If the cards are locked into an explicit type (member, checklist) then your approach totally works, but Trello lets you add/remove special extensions as you see fit. A card might have any number of permutations of the "extended" fields and it doesn't seem reasonable to make every combination as a extended class. Its almost like they modify the card "data" structure on the fly based on what the user wants to include.

Comment: To illustrate, I can have a card [default+member] or [default+member+image] or [default+checklist+image] or [default+duedate+checklist] - the core extensions are checklist/image/duedate... but you can have any combination of those added to a card, something doesn't feel right about making an extended class to account for each combination... the code duplication horror....

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles into this and has a similar question, the concept I was missing and needed to make my set up work is a Controller, which makes sense since those are missing from BB by default.

I needed something to hold a reference to widgets which may or may not be added to a "card" arbitrarily. A Collection didnt seem quite right in this case but a self created Controller class does the trick.